# Mudança da aparência do site

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Essa aparência do site já esta ultrapassada, visitei outros sites da StackEnchange e achei eles lindos, bem organizado e uma aparência boa. Por que o StackOverflow PT não melhora sua interface um pouco ou vocês tem planos para modificar algo no site? Pelo menos a fonte?

> Para a equipe StackOverflow PT: **Vocês pretendem mudar a aparência do site?**
>
> Para você: **Você gosta ou queria mudar a aparência do site?**

**Eu fiz um conceito** de um estilo próprio para o StackOverflow PT, não baseei em nenhum site e não usei nenhuma linguagem de design, misturei várias, aqui está um dos exemplos com a marca da água de códigos no fundo (códigos na linguagem Visual Basic):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Aqui com a marca da água da linguagem XML**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tirando a cor bege para o fundo, ficou muito massa! Sinceramente eu gostaria se eles trocassem para esse layout aí(mas sem a cor bege) até porque ficaria bem mais "espaçoso" e organizadinho.

Comment: Na minha humilde opinião, essa cor de fundo, vai se tornar cansativa, após o uso continuo, fora isso ficou bacana!

Comment: Coloquei a cor beje para promover a cor laranja do site, mas se deixasse branco ia ficar legal também

Comment: Eu prefiro como está agora. Eu até preferia é como estava antes de mudar...

Answer (score 12):

Talvez fosse mais legal em vez de uma proposta genérica e aberta *"Vocês pretendem mudar a aparência do site?"* que fizesse sugestões específicas, tipo "Esta é minha idéia para tal parte do site".

Não acho que colocar uma cor ou *background* no fundo facilita a leitura. O desenho atual me parece bem limpo, e para meu gosto pessoal está bom do jeito que está. Lembro também que este site é mais que nada "texto", *quem vem aqui quer ver solução* e quer ver isso fácil. Um dos lemas da rede é ["**Sem distrações**"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Para fazer uma proposta de alterações bem sucedida, é melhor estudar o que já foi discutido a respeito aqui neste Meta, e melhor ainda se puder [**conferir os arquivos do Metão**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (em Inglês).

Sinceramente, acho que esta não vai para diante, mas por favor continue exercitando a defesa de idéias. Pode ser que não emplaque aqui, garanto que tem utilidade na vida real :)

Answer (score 9):

Não precisa pedir para a equipe do SOPt mudar. Você pode desenvolver a folha de estilo em separado [e escrever um componente para trocar a folha de estilo através do navegador](http://www.omnimint.com/A6/JavaScript/Change-external-CSS-stylesheet-file-with-JavaScript.html).

Comment: Não mexo com CSS nem JS :\

Comment: Pede pro [@OnoSendai](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1897/onosendai) que ele faz uma customização client-side para você :)

Answer (score 5):

Não tenho como falar sobre o que vai ser no futuro, mas por enquanto o design de todos os Stack Overflows vai ser sempre o mesmo, talvez com algumas alterações por conta das diferentes línguas.

A evolução do layout é constante. Pequenas alterações são feitas constantemente, para adaptar para novas funcionalidades, corrigir erros ou outras mudanças. E elas são sempre feitas com base em um conjunto razoavelmente restrito de normas:

- Tem que dar destaque absoluto ao conteúdo
- Tem que ser leve e rápido
- Tem que ser funcional

Existem outras coisas, mas não sou designer...

No final das contas, a sugestão do @brasofilo faz todo sentido. O melhor é identificar um problema específico ("O quadro de avisos tem pouco destaque" por exemplo) e propor uma solução para ele no Meta - preferencialmente o MSO.