# Nosso layout vai ficar igual ao do SO?

Tags: debate, layout

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4157/18246) aqui do Meta, o Gabe diz:

> [...] mas por enquanto o design de todos os Stack Overflows vai ser sempre o mesmo [...]

Isso quer dizer que o *layout* do **SOpt** vai mudar? Ou os *layouts* não serão mais iguais?

## EDIT

**Página inicial do SOen**
[image: Soen]

**Nossa página inicial**
[image: Sopt]

Comment: Até antes da graduação do site o SOen tinha o layout novo e o SOpt o antigo, acho que era sobre isso a questão linkada.

Comment: Nosso layout já é igual ao do SOen, não?

Comment: Não brinca comigo @Gabe :/

Comment: Cheguei conferir aqui, pra mim não é igual não Oo

Comment: O que que tá diferente?

Comment: As abas na página inicial, recomendação de uso das tags

Comment: Poderiam postar uns prints? Também não consegui notar a diferença.

Comment: @Math coloquei prints da página inicial

Comment: Ué... no meu tá ["normal"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l14OB.png)

Comment: @Math no meu também.

Answer (score 10):

Parabéns! Você está testando nossa nova navegação:

[New navigation for Stack Overflow is in alpha testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814/175506)
[New navigation, alpha 2 released](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259220/175506)

Suas abas estão diferentes porque, no seu perfil do SOen, você indicou que quer fazer parte do alpha e testar a nova navegação.

Para fazer parte - ou deixar de fazer parte - do alpha, é só ir nas [preferências do seu perfil no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) e procurar o checkbox no fundo da página:

[image: É um box, que você dá um check]