# Barra de navegação do Stack Overflow em inglês, quando teremos?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, stackexchange-button

Admito que no começo, essa barra me perturbou, mas não em geral, são alguns detalhes que eu realmente acho que deveriam mudar, mas no geral mesmo ela esta boa.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre o que eu desgosto ainda nela, o foco é outro, gostaria de saber, existe previsão para o nosso site (SOpt) e outros sites da rede para usa-la (ou talvez somente os SOs)?

[image: barra navegação]

Comment: Duplicata? [Nosso layout vai ficar igual ao do SO?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4367/18246). Mesmo se tratando do outro layout, acho que a resposta é a mesma.

Comment: @jbueno então essa que você linkou fala daquelas abas experimentais, eu estou falando especificamente do menu de navegação

Comment: Opa, SOpt atualizou o layout, e ai @GuilhermeNascimento, resolvido? kk

Comment: @David o Bigown já adicionou a tag [meta-tag:status-pronto]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Já temos. Viva a nova barra de navegação! :D

Comment: Achei que tinha errado a url

Comment: Todo mundo :D Como eu cliquei em algo já aberto achei que era bug, entrou o o SOen, Como ainda tava sonolento achei estranho, aí fui percebendo que tuso estava em português, até as perguntas, levou alguns segundos pra cair a ficha :D

Comment: Não vi nenhum anúncio? Não fizeram?

Comment: @EMBarbosa O Gabe está em férias.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ahhh!! Isso explica muita coisa...

Comment: Nada de aprontar no chat, hein molecada? kkkkk @EMBarbosa

Comment: @bfavaretto patrão fora... eheheheh